# ReactJS : Async function with axios call makes axios call in componentDidUpdate to return promise

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have the code of my component like :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import {
    Table
} from 'reactstrap';

const Adhoc = async (props) => {
  let cost = await props.cost(props.adhoc._id)

  return(
    <tr>
      <td>{props.adhoc.jIssue}</td>
      <td>{props.adhoc.paid ? "Paid" : "Not paid"}</td>
      <td>APP{props.adhoc.sprint}</td>
      <td>£{cost.data[0]}</td>
    </tr>
  )}

export default class QAdhocsDisplay extends Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    this.costingAdhoc = this.costingAdhoc.bind(this)

    this.state = {
      adhocs: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/adhocs/retrieve')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ adhocs: response.data })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
}

async costingAdhoc(id) {
  const data = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/jira/issue/' + id)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })

  return data;


}

adhocsList() {
    return this.state.adhocs.map(currentadhoc=> {
      return <Adhoc adhoc={currentadhoc} cost={this.costingAdhoc} key={currentadhoc._id}/>;
    })
  }

render(){
    return (
      <div className="toborder" style = {{paddingBottom: "59px"}}>
              <div className="display" style ={{backgroundColor: "#5394b2"}}>
                <h5 style = {{padding:"13px"}}>Adhoc status</h5>
                </div>
                <div className="table">
                <Table size="sm" bordered striped>
                <thead className="thead-light">
                    <tr className="adhocs">
                    <th className="sticky-column medium" >Adhoc issue</th>
                    <th className="sticky-column medium" >Payment status</th>
                    <th className="sticky-column medium" >Sprint</th>
                    <th className="sticky-column medium" >Projected cost</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    { this.adhocsList() }
                </tbody>
                </Table>
                </div>
            </div>
    )}
```

}

My issue is that I have the function `costingAdhoc(id)` which I pass as a prop to the child component `Adhoc`. To be able to access the information from the axios call I need these both functions to be async.

A child component of type `Adhoc` will be rendered for each item in the state that will get mapped in the function `adhocsList()`. For some reason this causes the axios call in the `componentDidUpdate()` to throw this error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If
>   you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

And  the error points to the line where I set the state. This means that the `costingAdhoc(id)` function async nature causes my axios call in the `componentDidUpdate()` function only return a promise and not the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem that is `Adhoc` component which you're declaring as a child component is actually a promise.
Why?
A function that is declared as `async` returns promise by default, so even if you return:

```
<tr>
      <td>{props.adhoc.jIssue}</td>
      <td>{props.adhoc.paid ? "Paid" : "Not paid"}</td>
      <td>APP{props.adhoc.sprint}</td>
      <td>£{cost.data[0]}</td>
</tr>
```

you're actually returning it wrapped inside a promise. React components cannot be promises.

Comment: As I mention in the question I get the error when I set the state with my axios call from from the `componentDidUpdate()` method. When I don't include the result from the method in the Child component I still get the same error.